# php csv to array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am fairly new to php and got this from a stack overflow question and cant seem to get it to work for me.

```
<?php
if (($handle = fopen("fullbox.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    echo "<pre>".print_r($data)." <br /></pre>";
}
fclose($handle);
}
echo $data[1];
?>
```

I need to set up a couple arrays for pricing using a large number of products(which I can pull from my csv file)  Fullbox.csv consists of just 10 numbers with 2 decial places.  I have just been trying to test this and this is the output that I get:

Array
(
    [0] => 8.53
)

Array
(
    [0] => 4.74
)

Array
(
    [0] => 5.00
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2.50
)

Array
(
    [0] => 6.48
)

Array
(
    [0] => 3.99
)

Array
(
    [0] => 8.53
)

Array
(
    [0] => 4.74
)

Array
(
    [0] => 8.53
)

Array
(
    [0] => 4.74
)

Why is the array setting all values in the [0} place holder of the array and also why is there a 1 in between each line.  Thanks in advance.

*Update* If this is a ten item array this should then return the value of the 1 entry in the array but it doesn't.  I essentially just need to store all of the prices so I can use them as variables later.  I don't need them to be printed. Thanks again.

```
echo $data[1];
```

Comment: The reason you get the 1 is because `print_r` isn't meant to be echoed, and it's just returning the boolean true, which is interpreted as 1.

Comment: Please post the output as text, not as an image. It would also help to see the CSV file you're parsing.

Comment: use print_r($data, true) for returning the print_r value

Comment: http://php.net/manual/de/function.print-r.php

Comment: If you have an array with only one entry at index `0`, why are you trying to access index `1`?

Comment: Those are not my intentions.  I wish to have an array with 10 seperate entries that I can save and call later in my program.

Comment: Then simply put every first child of those arrays in a previous declared array . Then only look into that array.

Answer (score 2):

`print_r` does not *return* the formatted array by default; it outputs it and returns `1`. Pass `true` as a second parameter.

```
echo "<pre>".print_r($data, true)." <br /></pre>";
```

All the values are in the `0` index of the array because arrays start at `0`. There is nothing wrong there.

Comment: If the array starts at 0 should it not end at 9 then since it consists of ten items??  How can I call the values independently if they are all set in the initial spot zero.   **echo$data[1];** returns nothing.Thanks again.

Comment: @Djacksway: Instead of using `print_r` to display them each time, append them to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$f = fopen(yourfile, "r");
$fs = filesize(yourfile);
$content = fread($f, $fs);

$lines = explode("\n", $content);
$result = array();
foreach($lines as $line) $result[] = explode(",", $line);
```

Comment: So instead of using a built-in function specifically designed to parse CSV, the OP should ditch that and use a half-baked custom parser?

Comment: :-) sometimes it's easier to understand if you are new in php, if you get a hint, how something works inside

Comment: You get a +1 from me if you can explain why this works but `fgetcsv()` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

CSV as in Comma Seperated-Values is an array each line. So each line -even if it has only 1 value- is array.

Also you don't need to echo "print_r".

Answer (score 0):

you also read the data from the CSV  using the following function and sort using the usort() function.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-sort-a1a2-z9z10aa1aa2-az9az10-using-php/

```
 Read data from the CSV

function readCSV() {
 $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
 array_shift($csv); //remove headers
 $csvData = splitandSort($csv);
 createCSV($csvData);
}
```